# Did Harley Quinn kill Robin?

Tags: dc, batman, robin

Did Harley Quinn kill Robin, was she just an accomplice, or was she uninvolved completely?

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, you are looking for the comics continuity, not the recent movies?

Answer (score 11):

## Comic-wise...No

[**Harley Quinn**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley_Quinn) first appeared in *Batman: The Animated Series* in September 1992.

Whereas Jason Todd was 'killed' in "[***A Death in the Family***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_A_Death_in_the_Family)" which is a four-issue Batman comic book story arc first published by DC Comics in Batman #426-429 from **1988 - 1989**

[image]

Since Harley didn't exist at the time Jason was killed, she **couldn't** have been involved.

---

## Movie-wise....Sorta

There's an onscreen graphic that Harley was an **accomplice** to the murder of Robin in *Suicide Squad*.

However, since there is no "real" name for the *Robin* in question, we don't know *which* Robin this refers too.

[image]

Comment: To be fair, there are some crazy retcons in comics.